# Get Timezone to take effect

Tags: django

I am going through the Django tutorial.
I thought the TIME_ZONE in settings.py was of form 'UTC-5', but it isn't.
I replaced it with 'America/Chicago'

However, when I do:

```
python manage.py shell

from django.utils import timezone
timezone.now()
```

I get 'UTC'
How do I get the timezone to take effect?

Comment: It is taking effect. Django tries to keep all python dates timezone aware and in the UTC time zone. The effect of `TIME_ZONE` is with input and output of times: If you render a template with a time in it that's timezone aware, it'll be localised to the `TIME_ZONE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be confusing. If you run the code below, you will see that it is set, but it won't output as you expect:

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.get_current_timezone() # Should be 'America/Chicago'
timezone.now() # should show UTC
```

If you want it to output in the shell with your set timezone, use `timezone.localtime()`

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.localtime()
```